# How do I get the filenames from xamarin forms resource directory

Tags: xamarin

I loaded 25 mp3 files into my Xamarin forms resource directory.  My objective is to get the file names from the resource directory and populate a picker control.  Can someone help me with some code samples?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it using a dependency service for each platform. Then you can read the files in the resource folder, filter the files ending with .mp3, and then return an array or list of the file names.

Comment: i cant seem to get the correct path to the resource file!

Comment: @BobBarbara Where exactly are the files stored? In your PCL project, or in your Droid/iOS/UWP projects? I'm not too clear what you mean by Xamarin Forms resource directory.